# how to modify existing pine-script code from @version2 to @version4?

Tags: pine-script

how to resolve the Undeclared identifier 'i1' error in pine script.

```
source=close
c2 = 0.74

i1 = c1*source + c2*nz(i1[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error said, you have to declare `i1`, starting with @version3.
In version 3 we declare it with `na`, but from version 4 we declare it with `0.0`, then you can write your formula/code and assign it to the same variable with `:=` (if you use `=` to the same variable, you will get an error, `The variable is already defined...`)

```
i1 = 0.0
i1 := c1*source + c2*nz(i1[1])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Your answer showed up in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue (which I believe is automatic for code-only answers). On an average day I go through 20-40 answers such as yours, so I generally use canned responses to save time. The answer may seem obvious to you, but to reviewers unfamiliar with this language it most certainly is not, so I cannot judge whether your snippet is correct. I do not know the difference between `=` and `:=`, nor why this language requires the use of one before the other. These are things that could be added to your answer.

Comment: Done, now everybody should be happy

Comment: you just made my day...blessings